# How to put argument (table name) of function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, postgres-14

I am using PostgreSQL 14.4 . My script

```sql
-- 0.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tenant;
CREATE TABLE tenant
(
    id               smallint primary key,
    company_tax_code character varying(14),
    period           character varying(16), -- 2021070420220705
    created          timestamp with time zone
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_id_tenant()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE

BEGIN
    new.id = (select coalesce(max(id), -32769) from tenant) + 1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_without_id_tenant
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON tenant
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_id_tenant();

CREATE INDEX tenant_idx ON tenant (id);
COMMIT;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 4.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account_object_bank_account;
CREATE TABLE account_object_bank_account
(
    id                smallint,
    account_object_id smallint not null,
    bank_account      character varying(64),
    bank_name         character varying(128),
    bank_id           smallint,
    sort_order        smallint,
    bank_branch_name  character varying(256),
    province          character varying(128),
    tenant_id         smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tenant_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tenant FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenant (id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION account_object_bank_account_setId()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE

BEGIN
    new.id = (select coalesce(max(id), -32769) from account_object_bank_account where tenant_id = new.tenant_id) + 1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER account_object_bank_account_trig_insertWithoutId
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON account_object_bank_account
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE account_object_bank_account_setId();

CREATE INDEX account_object_bank_account_idx ON account_object_bank_account (id, tenant_id);

COMMENT ON TABLE public.account_object_bank_account IS 'Bảng lưu tài khoản ngân hàng của khách hàng';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account_object_bank_account.id IS 'PK';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account_object_bank_account.account_object_id IS 'FK';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account_object_bank_account.bank_account IS 'Số TK ngân hàng';
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.account_object_bank_account.bank_name IS 'Tên ngân hàng';
COMMIT;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 5.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account_object_belong_to_group;
CREATE TABLE account_object_belong_to_group
(
    id                      smallint,
    account_object_id       smallint,
    account_object_group_id smallint,
    tenant_id               smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tenant_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tenant FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenant (id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION account_object_belong_to_group_setId()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE

BEGIN
    new.id = (select coalesce(max(id), -32769) from account_object_belong_to_group where tenant_id = new.tenant_id) + 1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER account_object_belong_to_group_trig_insertWithoutId
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON account_object_belong_to_group
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE account_object_belong_to_group_setId();

CREATE INDEX account_object_belong_to_group_idx ON account_object_belong_to_group (id, tenant_id);
COMMIT;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want re-use this custom function, then put argument of function is table name:

```sql
account_object_bank_account_setId()
account_object_belong_to_group_setId()
```

to

```
set_id( table_name )
```

argument sample: `account_object_bank_account`, `account_object_belong_to_group`.

How to do?

Answer (score 0):

update your 2 triggers with set_id('table_name')

and use TG_ARGV[] to retrieve the parameter in the trigger function

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: It did not work. Be carefully with your answer.

Comment: Did you update your 2 triggers?

Comment: No, I just need re-use a function for SQL script compacting.

Comment: At least, it is `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setId(my_table text)` , not `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setId(TEXT my_table)`

Comment: Yes, but your trigger must call your fucntion with the correct parameter (table name)

Comment: Your script even did not work with 1 table. Your answer should be vote down.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/f6c8524fbb177ff6be3d1a0dd81ad8cb and https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/180747077-9b472b64-c7f8-4464-92c2-5b1ae46d8d34.png

Comment: replace $1 by table_name ($1 is SQL syntax , you use plpgsql)

Comment: Still not work. You should careful with your answer.

Comment: Answer updated, I knew it works but i did not remember how :-)